# How to hide THIS element when I click THIS element's close button (with multiple elements)

Tags: javascript, this

I have an alert box that has its own close button. I didn't know users would be placing multiple instances of it on a web page.

Currently, when the close button of an element is clicked, only the first instance gets hidden. I can't close the other one after that. When I click *its* close button, nothing happens.

I want to be able to click each element's close button to hide that element and have the ability to hide the elements one at a time.  I feel like it has something to do with the THIS keyword, but I'm not sure.

Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="dcom-c__alert">
<div class="dcom-c-alert__icon">
    <svg class="dcom-c-alert__icon--alert" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
        <use xlink:href="/public/icons/cbds-icons-ui.svg#error-circle">
        </use>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="dcom-c-alert__message">
    <div role="alert" class="dcom-c-alert-copy">Alert: Due to the weather in NC, our branches are closed Tuesday 2/27/21.
    <a href="#" class="dcom-c-alert__icon--message" aria-label="Learn more about this alert.">Learn more                                    
        <svg role="presentation" class="dcom-c-alert__icon--chevron" focusable="false"
            width="20" height="20">
            <use href="/public/icons/cbds-icons-ui.svg#chevron-right"
                xlink:href="/public/icons/cbds-icons-ui.svg#chevron-right">
            </use>
        </svg>                                    
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button class="dcom-c-close-alert-wrapper" aria-label="Close">
    <svg class="cbds-c-icon cbds-c-iconButton__icon alert-close" focusable="true">
        <use href="../../../public/icons/cbds-icons-ui.svg#close"
            xlink:href="../../../public/icons/cbds-icons-ui.svg#close"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Here's my JavaScript code. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

```
const alert = document.querySelector('#dcom-c-alert');
const hideAlert = document.querySelector('.dcom-c-close-alert-wrapper');

function closeAlert() {
    alert.classList.add('hide');
}

hideAlert.addEventListener('click', function () {
    closeAlert();
});

hideAlert.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    // ADA: Next button activates with spacebar or enter key
    if (e.key === " " || e.key === "Enter" || e.key === "Spacebar") {
        closeAlert();
    }
});
```

Comment: attach html please

Comment: I just added it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reading this post, I gained some clarity and solved my own issue. The key was creating a temporary variable (**alert**, in my case) to hold the index of the current alert.

[How can delete the clicked item using the click event if all items have the same Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481700/how-can-delete-the-clicked-item-using-the-click-event-if-all-items-have-the-same)

Here's my JavasScript:

```
alerts.forEach(alert => {
    let alert = alerts[i];
    closeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert.remove();
    });
});
```